# Polymer hide drawer on big screens

Tags: html, polymer

This is my third question in one week about the Polymer SDK, I'm really sorry about that. Basically I'm trying to hide the drawer of the `<paper-drawer-panel>` element on a big screen, so that it looks like the mobile version, with this nice hamburger-menu i have coded with the `<paper-icon-button>` component.

In the official catalog I have found the attribute `forceNarrow` which I implemented like this.

```
<paper-drawer-panel forceNarrow>
```

But this does not take any effect on my actual "big-screen" website

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that the new attribute to property mapping in Polymer 1.0 can be a bit confusing.

You would actually have to use a `force-narrow` attribute in HTML that maps to the `forceNarrow` property in JS.

```
<paper-drawer-panel force-narrow>
```

See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping

Comment: This works, I wonder why the SO hasn't marked this as the right answer. The polymer docs are well documented but few examples on how to implement it exists. +1 for the effort.